# Python - automating the creation of class instances

Tags: python, class, instantiation

I have dozens of classes built in this fashion:

```
class playlist_type_1(radio):
    '''child class'''   
    def __init__(self,user, type):
        radio.__init__(self, user, type)


class playlist_type_2(radio):
    '''child class'''       
        def __init__(self,user,type):
            radio.__init__(self, user, type)
```

they inherit from:

```
class radio(self, user, type):
   '''parent class'''
```

since I will have many `users`, I'm trying build a model for creating instances like so:

```
thom = playlist_type1('Thom Yorke', 'playlist_type_1')
```

the user himself, `thom`, will chose his `playlist_type_n` at `command line` via:

```
string = raw_input('Choose a playlist type> ')
```

and instance will be created and run:

```
thom = playlist_type1('Thom Yorke', string)
```

can this be implemented within `class scope`?

Comment: What do you mean "within class scope"?

Comment: I mean using the code above, as class methods.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do that isn't accomplished by the code you have. What is the purpose of `playlist_type_2` and the other dozens of classes? Did you mean to say that, if the user inputs "playlist_type_2", then you want to create an instance of `playlist_type_2` instead of `playlist_type_1`? In other words, do you want to use the string inputted by the user as the name of the class to instantiate? Also, why is there a need for so many different classes in the first place, rather than just using `radio` instances with a `playlist_type` field holding an enumeration value?

Comment: A lot of your questions (and there are a lot) give the impression that you're struggling with some fundamental Python concepts and don't have a clear direction on your program's structure. I recommend spending some more time on independent research, with particular focus on OOP.

Comment: I think this site is meant to help those struggling, isn't it? Also, it was immediately clear to me what OP wanted despite him using wrong terms ("class methods", "class scope"). I think if question is related to something you have done yourself you will understand it no matter how poorly it is formulated. If you don't understand the question, perhaps you'd be more useful answering other questions.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to create a new playlist type per user? To what end? When I see *variables* named "X_1", "X_2", etc., this is a code smell that usually indicates a new user not really getting how to use a list of elements. But I don't think I've *ever* seen class names in this anti-pattern.

Comment: @jbasko - This site is meant to help those struggling, but asking questions is meant as a _supplement_ to independent research, not a replacement. Multiple poorly-received questions per day from a single user are a sign that that user needs to spend more time with instructional materials. It has nothing to do with how well I understand those questions, thanks.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thank you for your suggestion, but there is no such thing as 'independent' research. all knowledge acquired comes from others, be it from a book, from articles or from SO. also, you are not behind my shoulder to check how much I've been studying the matter using other sources. I think you assume too much and help too little.

Comment: "Independent research" means reading a book, articles, or other existing resources, rather than asking someone to just give you the answer.

Comment: I could show you a thousand SO posts with plenty of people asking for answers. your concept of research is different from mine. I respect yours, and I hope that you will respect mine.

Comment: Argumentum ad populum is not valid reasoning.

Comment: when you say that my questions were not well received by people, and use it to justify your reasoning of what should or should not be a valid post, is your reasoning not argumentum ad populum? btw, is not all SO system based on voting, that is, argumentum ad populum? upvoting, downvoting, badging etc. it's all argumentum ad populum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping of names to classes and then instantiate the class based on that:

```
class PlaylistType1(Radio):
    pass


class PlaylistType2(Radio):
    pass


playlist_types = {
    PlaylistType1.__name__: PlaylistType1,
    PlaylistType2.__name__: PlaylistType2,
}

...

playlist = playlist_types[chosen_type](user)
```